# Floating Basement Walls: Dealing with Doorways and Floor Cabinets

Tags: framing, basement-refinishing

There is quite a bit of information available on floating basement frames in areas with expansive soil, but there aren't many resources available to provide suggestions on how to handle doorways. The major problem I'm trying to prevent is having a massive gap between the door and the floor, in addition to preventing a similar gap between the trim and the floor. If I attach the jam to the floor plate, I'll effectively undo what I attempted to accomplish with the floated walls. How do people in areas with expansive soils deal with doorways and floating walls? A Google search provided a PDF that seems to provide some [insight on floating walls](http://blog.twinsprings.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/How-to-Build-a-Floating-Wall.pdf), but I'm afraid I'm not entirely following what is being suggested.

> The header casing will not be bound to the door header - the drywall
> will extend down behind the casing and float into the gap between the
> door header and the header casing. The header casing will only be
> bound to the side casing and the door jamb. The thick nails will
> connect the door header and the false door header, to work against
> shearing force. You can also add bolts and steel plates plates to the
> king studs, and cut channels (for floating) into the jack studs, so
> the sides of the door framing will also prevent shearing force (both
> sideways AND front to back) Note that the jack studs and king studs
> are not nailed together, and will rub up and down against each other
> (a miniscule) gap is suggested.

Is the casing essentially a standard jack with slots cut into it to allow it to slide alongside the king stud? In the image below (taken from the link above), is the **header** attached on the right side of the casing, but left unattached on the left (held in place by the drywall)? If I understand the quoted text correctly, the door would be attached to the side with the casing. Does that sound right? Lastly, I believe the suggestion is to completely avoid the studs that would typically be placed above the header so that the header can float freely, but I was imagining I could still place overhead studs and simply attach a 2x4 at the top of them that is affixed to the top plate via 60D nails (essentially the opposite of how all of the other walls in my basement are finished, where the 60D nails are driven into the base plate). Thoughts on this?

[image: Example Floating Doorway]

The other major concern I have is dealing with cabinets that would normally attach to the floor and walls. This would obviously, like the door jams, effectively undo whatever attempt I previously made to float the walls because it would make everything work as a single unit. How do people generally handle cabinets that are on the floor when dealing with floated basement walls?

**Update:** I'll be handling the jack stud on the casing side using this design:

[image: Slots and slag bolts in jack studs]

Comment: Wouldn't a more logical solution but to move the walls a little away from the foundation?    I really do not get this.   If my foundation is moving in because of soil moving my framing and drywall is the least of my concerns.

Comment: @DMoore the problem is the entire basement slab is intentionally designed to float. Some people suggest you don't need to bother if you're framing against an external wall, but the code in my area doesn't differentiate between internal and external walls. In any case, this doorway is part of an interior wall.

Comment: @DMoore this link describes it slightly better than I can - https://homefixcos.com/frame-basement-colorado-springs/

Comment: OK that makes more sense.   I got from your question that your walls may move.  I could see the slab system moving.   I don't really get the issue with the doorway.   Casings aren't attached to the ground.   You could effectively just frame everything exactly the same and just not nail down the bottom plate.   Casings for sure do not need to be nailed to the bottom plate.

Comment: @DMoore I think I'm partially to blame because I don't know the terminology as well as I wish I did and this is all very new to me. I was originally thinking the term "casing" was something somebody came up with to differentiate a slotted jack stud from a standard jack stud, but after reading your comment and looking at the picture I shared, I get the impression "casing" refers to the molding. With that confusion out of the way, I *believe* the problem is that the jack connects to the ground, so perhaps all of this is nonsense and I would simply....not connect it to the ground. (1/2)

Comment: @DMoore If I modified the design from the picture above and simply connected the jack studs to the floating base board, I risk having the floor come up and jam the door. I could then trim it off and go on my merry way, but it might settle again and leave me with a large gap. More importantly, the molding, itself, goes to the floor. What happens if the floor goes up? It would want to push the entire wall up with it. (2/2)

Comment: So is the expansion of the soil - the floating part a mechanism to keep the floor moving horizontal or vertical or both?   I have a hard time thinking that a basement floor - 4-5' under bury at least would move up or down and have a hard time believing that basement wouldn't flood if it did.     I need more info before I can help more.   I were that worried about it I would wait and cycle through the seasons to see the effect or at least get neighbors input.  If a floor shifts 1/2" horizontally... easy... vertical not hard but wondering if you would pass leaving gaps.   Doors don't change.

Comment: @DMoore the floating design is intended to allow horizontal movement, up/down. The county I live in mandates non-bearing, basement walls be built to accommodate a minimum of 1.5" of floor movement. I've been erring on the side of caution by providing 2" of float for the basement walls I've already built.